# Understanding use of factor theorem to factor polynomial based on possible factors from constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm reviewing my algebra in prep for Linear Algebra, using the review of Algebra in Stewart's Single Variable Calculus, here: http://stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS_8E_ET/upfiles/6et_reviewofalgebra.pdf

On p.4, they use the Factor Theorem to factor $$x^3 - 3x^2 -10x + 24$$

They state the following:

> If P(b) = 0, where b is an integer, then b is a factor of 24.

They then use this fact to test possible integer values of b as a factor of 24 (+1, -1, +2, -2, etc.).  What I'm not understanding is how they arrive at the fact that b must be a factor of 24 based on the the Factor Theorem.  I understand from the Factor Theorem that if P(b) = 0, then x - b will be a factor of P(x), but how did they discern that b would be a factor of 24?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), every rational root $q_0$ of a polynomial $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ with integer coefficients can be written as $\frac ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $b$ divides $a_n$ and $a$ divides $a_0$. In your case, $a_n=1$ and $a_0=24$. So, $q$ must be an integer that divides $24$.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand.  Not surprisingly I also had forgotten the rational root theorem, so here's a video for anyone who stumbles on to this and is in the same predicament.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs0S9LpuxmE

Answer (score 0):

If $(x-b)$ is a factor, then $f(x)=g(x)(x-b)$, Assuming the constant term of $f$ is nonzero, then one must have that $b$ times the constant term of $g$ is the constant term of $f$. This tells us that $b$ must divide the constant term of $f$.

Comment: There is no need to assume the constant term of $f$ is nonzero.  On the other hand, it is necessary to know that $g(x)$ has integer coefficients (or at least integer constant term), which you can prove using the division algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

The product of all roots of this polynomial is $24$ as you can see. Also $b$ is a root of this polynomial as given $P(b)=0$. Therefore $b$ must be a factor of $24$.

Comment: But it is possible that not all the roots are integers.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey But it is mentioned that b is an integer in the question asked. That's why I didn't mentioned that explicitly in my answer.

Comment: You know that $b$ times the other two roots is $24$.  But if the other two roots are not integers, this does not tell you $b$ is a factor of $24$.

Comment: Sorry... I got the point. Thanks for telling me...